# indexing trouble in linked list

Tags: python, indexing

I am just having some trouble with setting up the index for part of my code. The key function is switch() everything else is fine. The switch functions job is to take the node at the given index and switch it with the node at the head of the list. I am so close but I can't figure out why when I run the test function (testswitch()) for the first case it won't output the first two nodes and then because the list is already altered the second test case won't run through due to a TypeError. Any help is appreciated

```
"""
Creates and returns a linked list containing all of the elements
of the Python-style list parameter.
"""

def createList(plist):

    myList = None 
    for index in range(len(plist)-1, -1, -1):
        myList = insertValueHead(myList, plist[index])
    return myList

'''
Creates a string representation of the values in the linked list such as:
5->6->9->14.
'''

def listString(linkedList):


      ptr = linkedList
      str1 = ''
      while ptr != None:
        str1 += str(ptr['data'])
        ptr = ptr['next']
        if ptr != None:
          str1 += "->"
      str1 = str1
      return str1


'''
Inserts a new node containing the value "value" to the head of the list.
LinkedList is the head of the list to be added to
Value is the data to be stored in the node
'''

def insertValueHead(myList, value):

    newnode = {}
    newnode["data"] = value
    #set the next pointer of this new node to the head of the list, linkedList
    #newnode is now the head of the list 
    newnode["next"] = myList
    return newnode

def nthNode(myList, index):

    ptr = myList
    count = 0
    if index < 0:
        return None
    while ptr != None and count < index:
        ptr = ptr['next']
        count += 1
    return ptr

def switch(myList, index):

    newnode = {}
    newnode['data'] = 0
    newnode['next'] = None
    temphead = myList
    head = myList
    head = head['next']
    if index != 0:
        output = myList
    else:
        output = newnode
    prev, ptr = None, myList
    while ptr != None and index >0:
        prev = ptr
        ptr = ptr['next']
        index = index - 1
    if index > 0:
        print ('Index out of range')
    temphead['next'] = ptr['next']
    ptr['next'] = head
    prev['next'] = temphead
    print ptr['data']
    return output



def testSwitch():

    #test code to ensure that switch() is working correctly.
    myList = createList([10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60])
    print "The initial list", listString(myList)
    myList = switch(myList, 2)
    print "Switching the head and the 30.  Resulting list is ", listString(myList)
    myList = switch(myList, 5)
    print "Switching the head and the 60.  Resuling list is ", listString(myList)
    myList = switch(myList, 29)  #should result in an error   
testSwitch()
```

This is the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Hassan/Desktop/Python/assignment4.py", line 122, in <module>
    testSwitch()
  File "C:/Users/Hassan/Desktop/Python/assignment4.py", line 119, in testSwitch
    myList = switch(myList, 5)
  File "C:/Users/Hassan/Desktop/Python/assignment4.py", line 105, in switch
    temphead['next'] = ptr['next']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: Could you please include the entire Traceback?

Comment: Nvm I figured it out!

Comment: however, any idea why that type error occurs? because it's occuring in my fixed code too and I would like to know what causes it

Comment: As the docs put it `TypeError` is raised when an operation or function is applied to an object of inappropriate type. In this case it occurs because `ptr` is likely `None` when you attempt to do `temphead['next'] = ptr['next']`. When you access a dictionary's key using `[]` notation, python invokes the dict objects' `__getitem__` method. A `None` has no `__getitem__` defined. Hence the error.

Comment: I using a different code now where I am just setting a variable equal to the value inside ptr['data'], yet I still get this error how would  I fix it?